# React-Admin Enterprise Edition: Breadcrumb component with recordRepresentation does not display specified field

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-admin

I am working on the implementation of a Breadcrumb component in my React Admin project using the Enterprise edition.

The Breadcrumb is specified like this:

```
import { Breadcrumb } from '@react-admin/ra-navigation';

const MyBreadcrumb = () => (
    <Breadcrumb sx={{ marginTop: 2, marginLeft: 2 }}>
        <Breadcrumb.ResourceItems />
    </Breadcrumb>
);

export default MyBreadcrumb;
```

I then use it in my SciLayout.tsx file:

```
const SciLayout = (props: LayoutProps) => {
  return (
    <ProfileContextProvider>
      <Layout
        {...props}
        breadcrumb={<MyBreadCrumb />}
        menu={SciMenu}
        dashboard={SciDashboardPage}
        appBar={SciAppBar}
      />
    </ProfileContextProvider>
  );
```

This layout is then applied in through my App.tsx in my entire project:

```
import SciLayout from './layout/SciLayout';

const App = () => {
    <ThemeProvider>
      <Admin
        layout={SciLayout}
        dataProvider={NodeDataProviderEvents}
        authProvider={SciZitadelAuthProvider}>


        <Resource
          name='tasks'
          options={{ label: 'Meldungen' }}
          list={TaskList}
          show={TaskShow}
          icon={TaskAltIcon}
          recordRepresentation="name"
        />
      </Admin>
    </ThemeProvider>
};
```

The App.tsx is actually much larger but I left out all the styling and unnecessary pieces of code.
Routing etc. is all set up.

Note that an entry of a task in the database looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "648aa87bf9bc3f2d982140e1"
  },
  "id": "648aa87bf9bc3f2d982140e1",
  "name": "Zinsstatistik Juli 2023",
  "deadline": {
    "$date": "2023-06-30T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  "user": "Max Mustermann",
  "controller": "Maxine Mustermann",
  "currentStage": {
    "$oid": "644a2bfc20c9acb2f7ed9a3a"
  },
  "state": "OPEN",
  "taskDefinition": {
    "$oid": "644a2ae920c9acb2f7ed9988"
  },
  "maskStates": {
    "644a2bf220c9acb2f7ed9a34": {
      "tabIndex": "3"
    },
    "644a2bfc20c9acb2f7ed9a3a": {
      "uploaded1": true,
      "fileName1": "addresses.csv",
      "uploaded2": true,
      "fileName2": "spndTest.zip"
    },
    "644a2bf820c9acb2f7ed9a37": {
      "uploaded": true,
      "fileName": "testGIF.gif"
    },
    "6488236012f7f47b4706fcad": {
      "uploaded1": true,
      "fileName1": "pdf-teaser.png"
    }
  }
}
```

So in the original code, I did not use the recordRepresentation="name" meaning that the Breadcrumb component should go into the "tasks" database and look for the id field which it then would display. Currently it displays the id.
Since I want to display the "name" field inside of the task entry, I used the resourceRepresentation property as seen above and specified the field to be "name". However, it still displays only the id of the task entry.

The entire backend part works. There is a working connection with the database, the dataprovider is implemented and all entries of the database are read correctly as the network analysis of my browser shows.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you try to contact the [React Admin Support](https://marmelab.com/ra-enterprise/#support) about this? Since this is an Enterprise component, you should have access to their support desk too.

Comment: Finally recieved an answer, apparantly there were two seperate breadcrump components. I had been using the one from the wrong library apparantly. I should have been using the one from ra-enterprise instead of ra-navigation. Sorry for the late answer and thank you for the suggestion.